# How do I separate arrays and add them based on their index in the array?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x

I am trying to make a wage calculator where a user inserts a .txt file and the program calculates the number of hours worked.

So far I am able to separate the names, wage value, and hours, but I can't figure out how to add the hours together.

So my desired result would be:

Names of Employees
Wage (how much they make
Added number of hours per employee

Here is the data set (file name of txt is -> empwages.txt):

(Edit: the formatting is messed so heres a screen grab of the text: [image]

```
Spencer 12.75   8   8   8   8   10
Ruiz    18  8   8   9.5 8   8
Weiss   14.80   7   5   8   8   10
Choi    15  4   7   5   3.3 2.2
Miller  18  6.5 9   1   4   1
Barnes  15  7.5 9   4   0   2
```

Desired Outcome:

```
'Spencer', 'Ruiz', 'Weiss', 'Choi', 'Miller', 'Barnes'
'12.75', '18', '14.80', '15', '18', '15'
'42', '41.5', ... and so on
```

Current code:

```
infile = open("empwages.txt","r")
masterList = infile.readlines()

nameList = []
hourList = []
plushourList = []
for master in masterList:
    nameList.append(master.split()[0])
    hourList.append(master.split()[1])
    x = 2
    while x <= 6:
        plushourList.append(master.split()[x])
        x += 1


print(nameList)
print(hourList)
print(plushourList)
```

Comment: Are you opposed to using `pandas`? This would be a great package to consider for this type of problem.

Comment: not sure, ultimately i will be putting part of this code into a tkinter GUI https://imgur.com/a/Ry83ZiB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is useful that you get familar with the concept of [unpacking a list in Python](https://docs.python.org/3.7/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists). You can use the following code to solve your problem:

```
names = []
hours = []
more_hours = []
with open('empwages.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        name, hour, *more_hs = line.split()
        names.append(name)
        hours.append(hour)
        more_hours.append(more_hs)

print(*names, sep=', ')
print(*hours, sep=', ')
print(*[sum(float(q) for q in e) for e in more_hours])
```

In case you need the strings as you have requested:

```
names = []
hours = []
more_hours = []
with open('empwages.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        name, hour, *more_hs = line.split()
        names.append(name)
        hours.append(hour)
        more_hours.append(more_hs)

print(more_hours)

names = ', '.join(names)
hours = ', '.join(hours)
more_hours = ', '.join(str(s) for s in [sum(float(q) for q in e) for e in more_hours])


print(names)
print(hours)
print(more_hours)
```

#### Output

```
Spencer, Ruiz, Weiss, Choi, Miller, Barnes
12.75, 18, 14.80, 15, 18, 15
42.0 41.5 38.0 21.5 21.5 22.5
```

Comment: if I were to implement it into a tkinter gui, how would it be like? please see my imgur for reference. (https://imgur.com/a/Ry83ZiB)

Comment: @jimmyjohn123, what do you mean? I am no following your question.

Comment: The code you gave me works perfectly when used in a normal .py file, however, I am trying to implement your code into a gui interface. I am unable to use print(*[sum(float(q) for q in e) for e in more_hours]) as a print statement in the tkinter format.

Comment: @jimmyjohn123, got you, you need the string.

Comment: @jimmyjohn123, I updated the answer, now you have variables that you can use containing the string, and if you want to contatenate them, just use the string concatenation operator `+`.

Comment: thats great! I was wondering if I were to make more_hours = ', '.join(str(s) for s in [sum(float(q) for q in e) for e in more_hours]) a list, how would that work? I know that for the variables names and hours, I would just need to use the original variables without the .join function, but for the more_hours variable, some modification may be needed.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `zip`:

```
with open("empwages.txt") as f:
    lines = [line.split() for line in f]
    names, hours, *more_hours = zip(*lines)
    print(names)
    print(hours)
    print([sum(map(float, i)) for i in zip(*more_hours)])

('Spencer', 'Ruiz', 'Weiss', 'Choi', 'Miller', 'Barnes')
('12.75', '18', '14.80', '15', '18', '15')
[42.0, 41.5, 38.0, 21.5, 21.5, 22.5]
```

This will:

- Split the file up by line, and split the lines up by word
- Put the first word of each line in `names`, the second in `hours`, and the rest in more_hours

You can add more variables before the `*_` as needed.

(Edited to correctly sum hours).

Answer (score 0):

Well if you're not opposed to using `pandas`:

```
import pandas as pd
from StringIO import StringIO
import re

initial_data = '''Spencer 12.75   8   8   8   8   10
Ruiz    18  8   8   9.5 8   8
Weiss   14.80   7   5   8   8   10
Choi    15  4   7   5   3.3 2.2
Miller  18  6.5 9   1   4   1
Barnes  15  7.5 9   4   0   2'''

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(re.sub(r'[ ]+', ',', initial_data, flags=re.M)), header=None)
print(df)
     0      1    2  3    4    5     6
0  Spencer  12.75  8.0  8  8.0  8.0  10.0
1     Ruiz  18.00  8.0  8  9.5  8.0   8.0
2    Weiss  14.80  7.0  5  8.0  8.0  10.0
3     Choi  15.00  4.0  7  5.0  3.3   2.2
4   Miller  18.00  6.5  9  1.0  4.0   1.0
5   Barnes  15.00  7.5  9  4.0  0.0   2.0
```

Then you can quickly sum over the columns like so:

```
df.loc[:, 1:].sum(axis=1)
0    54.75
1    59.50
2    52.80
3    36.50
4    39.50
5    37.50
dtype: float64
```